# Game center get friend's games

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I am working on an app which uses game center. I would like to know if its possible to get a list of games of a player's friends in game center? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible.  It's not even possible to find out if any of your friends has installed your game.

Comment: You can get a list of friends that are playing the same game. You can load a person's friends with `GKLocalPlayer`'s `loadFriendsWithCompletionHandler`.

Comment: @MarcusAdams The docs don't mention "friends that are playing the same game". It's just `A list of player identifiers for the local player’s friends.`

Comment: @android, you then match those identifiers with the ones you store on the server.